# filtering results, manipulating data aspnet mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if anyone can suggest me a book or tutorial in order to enhance knowledge on data manipulation or filtering data results.

I would like to know how to create a query on Entity framework, pass that info to the controller and then manipulate data in a grid or list using checkboxes - eg only results with photo, etc - , price range sliders and more data results filtering from the UI.

Thank you so much.
ps: I have a tutorial in ajax but I`m looking in plain c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't suggest any book in particular but to do the things you've mentioned you should look into the following things:

- Learn about ASP.Net MVC's default Model Binder: that's how you get data to your controller in a clean way, any proper ASP.Net MVC should cover this
- Learn LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities: that's how you query the data. There are quite a few LINQ to Entities books out there.

Here's an up-to-date tutorial from Microsoft that covers pretty much what you are asking for: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs.

Once your have mastered this, I suggest you look into the Model View-View Model pattern. It will help with much more complex stuff but don't rush into it.

Cheers

Comment: thank you for you answer. I´ve been trying to find an example or tutorial displaying data filtering. At the moment I found datatables.net with an ajax example. Guys from rolla published some info at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Building_Dynamic_SQL.aspx , sommarks place some details at http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html for sql server 2008.

Comment: My pleasure! If you are using EF, stay away from dynamic SQL. You won't need it. What you want is EF, LINQ to EF, and the EF WHERE/SORT/TAKE/SKIP commands: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738636.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an up-to-date tutorial from Microsoft that covers all that what you are asking for: 
Also ,There is Complete project available in the link below you can go through it hope it will help you understanding all that you want to learn.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application